# get_object_or_404 latest = True

Tags: django

I want to retrieve the last object of a matching query. How can I get that?

Something like :

```
get_object_or_404(Passwordreset, otp=5)
```

My model has multiple objects with otp 5. Is there something by which I can get the last object which has otp=5?

Comment: How do you store the datatime of your `Passwordreset`?

Comment: Django’s auth framework comes with views to reset passwords. Are you sure you have to write your own?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

First filter all objects with opt=5 then you can use the [.last()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first) method to get the last object.

```
YourModel.objects.filter(opt=5).last()
```

Comment: If you do this, you can raise 404 by adding `if reset is None: raise Http404`. Remember the import `from django.http import Http404`. You might need to add `.order_by('timestamp')` to the queryset so that `last()` returns the correct object.

Comment: It says `AttributeError: 'Passwordreset' object has no attribute 'last'`

Comment: @YantraLogistics then you didn't follow the answer correctly.